# How to add custom label for Line Chart from Chart.js?

Tags: javascript, charts, chart.js, data-visualization

Let's imagine that I introduced new version of todo list in my application at 09-04-2017. I am getting results of survey that ask users for rate and opinion of that todo list. I want to watch how rates were going from that date. Please tell me how to add additional custom label for Line Chart from chart.js plugin. I am going to get something like this:

[image]

I would like to see that text when mouse is on it and it would be great if point will show on a curve maybe even with light grey dashed line connecting that 2 points. Is that possible in chart.js? Or maybe you know some other plugin that can do it?

My basic line chart looks like this:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('myChart');
var data = {
    labels: ["March Week 1", "March Week 2", "March Week 3", "March Week 4", "April Week 1", "April Week 2", "April Week 3", "April Week 4"],
    datasets: [
        {
            label: "My First dataset",
            backgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.2)",
            borderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            borderWidth: 2,
            hoverBackgroundColor: "rgba(255,99,132,0.4)",
            hoverBorderColor: "rgba(255,99,132,1)",
            data: [49, 51, 48, 52, 56, 73, 77, 73, 74],
        }
    ]
};
var option = {
 scales: {
   yAxes:[{
      stacked:true,
        gridLines: {
         display:true,
          color:"rgba(255,99,132,0.2)"
        }
    }],
    xAxes:[{
      gridLines: {
         display:false
        }
    }]
  }
};

var myBarChart = Chart.Line(canvas,{
 data:data,
  options:option
});
```

```html
<canvas id="myChart" width="400" height="200"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.1.3/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Please for help,

Arthur

Comment: Ok, snippet done :)

Comment: Getting a "Script error" when running the code snippet.